# read write string in windows application - internal

Tags: c#, wpf

How could I read/write specific string on my WPF application

It's must be internal and on my application

I have using 
CredentialManager
, but I lose data of it during reboot

```
CredentialManager.WriteCredential("title", "user, "pass");
```

Comment: What do you mean with "internal"? In order to survive a reboot it has to be stored somewhere. You can hash / encrypt it if it is sensitive data and store it in a file or database for example.

Comment: @PeterBons  I have using CredentialManager.WriteCredential("title", "user, "pass"); this code works fine, but after reboot , it's goes to be empty , so this is why I looking for another way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to write your data to a file or a database in order to be able to access them after a reboot.

In most of the cases you could simply use a `FileStream` and do your file read/writes. But from your example it looks like you're trying to save user credentials which is sensitive data, so should never be written/saved anywhere without proper security measures.

So using some sort of encryption algorithm is one good practice. .NET comes with its own basic `Encrypt` and `Decrypt` capabilities, but those are really basic. I don't know what level of security you'd want so it's really a judgement call on what to use.

If you prefer rather high level of encryption, [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14777732/302248) has some good answers on how to go about it. Hope this helps.