# What is the actual encryption level used for C# File.Encrypt and how secure is it?

Tags: c#, file, salesforce, aes, apex-data-loader

We are writing an windows service that needs to spit out a CSV that a third party application will then use to push up to a SaaS system. The third part tool and HTTPS stream to the SaaS tool is using TLS 1.2 and looks good.

My concern is the CSV at rest during the time the CSV (unencrypted data) is at rest.

one of our developers mentioned using C# File.Encrypt to encrypt the file by the service account running the last (Task Scheduler) and the same account would kick off the third part tool on a scheduled time and it would be decrypted.

As the title suggests, how secure is this or easy to crack? There will be PII information, so I want to make sure what we choose makes sense.

***UPDATE ***
 To provide some extra context, We are trying to use a SalesForce CRM tool called DataLoader. This is a batch import tool into SalesForce. The vendor we are working with wants us to trigger the executable based on a windows task scheduler. The scheduler would require us to have a file that they consume because DataLoader inherently does not support push, only pull from a local file. 
TRUST ME if I could.. a database it would be :). I'm not a fan of the solution and would rather go an API route into SalesForce, but I'm a bit limited at the moment

Comment: Instead of encrypting the file, you could set strict permissions on the folder where the file is stored, so that only the service creating the file, and the third party tool, has permissions to read it. This requires less weird plumbing.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encrypting_File_System

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding who is the attacker in this scenario; what's the vulnerability you're worried about and who is the attacker?

Comment: @EricLippert, the attacker would be someone gets into our network and gains control of that server. If i were a hacker, one thing I would do while on there is scan for files that have certain extensions, so I'm figuring, a CSV would be a potential find and having sensitive data in there seems like a pretty easy find for a hacker that now controls the server... Does that make sense?

Comment: @gnud - I think if someone got a hold of the server /local admin access, they could decrypt it with the RSA keys if I read your article properly.

Comment: Right, if the attacker is admin then all you can do is slow them down slightly; admins own the machine and can defeat your countermeasures.  Defense in depth is a great idea, but I would consider defending against less catastrophic attacks. For example, suppose someone gains non-admin access to the machine; in that case, gnud's suggestion is highly effective.

Comment: Admin can, for instance, install a programmatic debugger and then debug the process that is doing the encryption / decryption and read the plaintext from memory, so encryption doesn't stop the attack, it just makes it slightly harder.

Comment: @EricLippert don't disagree with the logic on the debugging, except that the example you reference the attacker would not only have to find the file, but also the process before being detected. My admin reference meant that all he had to do was be admin and find the file. That's much easier than also finding the right task / service
I think my biggest issue is that it is PII and will be in a server that is externally available (although very limited). The decryption

Comment: @EricLippert and @T McKeown - Any knowledge on how secure File.Encrypt is? It sounds like it uses DPAPI and RSA key which is pretty solid, so if the biggest issue is an admin account taking over control, I think it at least gets us better than just file permission settings. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Your developer is technically correct, if this is potential vulnerability then abandon it.  If you want more control of the actual encryption then here are some options:

[Encrypt a file using File.Encrypt and then Decrypt it to memory stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777732/encrypt-a-file-using-file-encrypt-and-then-decrypt-it-to-memory-stream)

Use a database.

Comment: I actually already have a utility I wrote that uses AesProvider and CryptoStream for encryption, so I'm familiar with that stuff and wish we could use it. 
In this case, we are trying to use a SalesForce CRM tool called DataLoader. This is a batch import tool into SalesForce. The vendor we are working with wants us to use it based on a windows task scheduler which would require us to have a file that they consume. TRUST ME if I could.. a database it would be :).
I'm not a fan of the solution and would rather go an API route into SalesForce, but I'm a bit limited at the moment

Comment: Also updating the question to include some of these details

Comment: @T McKeown - Any knowledge on how secure File.Encrypt is? It sounds like it uses DPAPI and RSA key which is pretty solid, so if the biggest issue is an admin account taking over control, I think it at least gets us better than just file permission settings. Thoughts?

Comment: that is my understanding also.